# getting error while posting data in elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch

I have added the following template to my elasticsearch

`POST _template/index
{
  "template": "logstash-*",
  "mappings": {
    "beatplanner": {
      "dynamic": "true",
      "properties": {
        "req_location": {
          "type": "geo_point"
        },
        "res_location": {
          "type": "geo_point"
        },
        "lat": {
          "type": "float"
        },
        "lon": {
          "type": "float"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}`

the idea was to map the `req_location` and `res_location` to the type `geo_point`

But when i am trying to put data to elasticsearch, i am getting the following errors

`[res_location] is defined as an object in mapping [log] but this name is already used for a field in other types`

i have checked mapping for all indices (logstash-*) but i don't see it getting defined anywhere else.

where else could the issue be?

Comment: In one of your `logstash-*` indexes, you must have a `log` mapping type with a field `res_location` being defined as `object` instead of `geo_point`. Can you update your question with the result you get from `curl -XGET localhost:9200/logstash-*` ?

Comment: retried adding the response but its exceeding the limit :( imposed by stackoverlow. I tried searching `res_location` but could not  find it "log"

Comment: You could [gist](https://gist.github.com/) the response

Comment: yes, was not aware of this :) 

the response is available here [link](https://gist.github.com/anonymous/71c6b73d8edfee8867e049194c6115ab)

Comment: How do you put new data into ES?

Comment: thru filebeat (thru logstash) in logstash i have the following filter `add_field => {
  "[req_location][lat]" => "%{[request_json][latitude]}"
  "[req_location][lon]" => "%{[request_json][longitude]}"
}`

further, i deleted the template `index` which i had createdand when i check the mapping, i see there is a mapping `req_location` but not sure where it is getting it from. Could  this be auto generated by elasticsearch ?

Comment: If ES sees a field that is not yet in ES, it will auto-map it and guess its content. So if you send `"req_location": {"lat":"...", "lon":"..."}`, the inferred type will be `object` and not `geo_point`

Comment: I think I have resolved the issue by renaming the document type from `beatplanner` to `log` which I believe was ignorance of how `document type` is used in ES